# Reason for Yaakov's [lack of] Kibud Av while in Haran

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

The Gemmorah ([Megilla 17a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.17a.6?lang=he&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=he)) mentions that Yaakov was punished for not honoring his parents for 22 years in Haran (but not for the 14 years at Ever's Yeshivah). His punishment was that his son Yossef was also "cut off" from him for 22 years:

> "ומנלן דלא מיענש דתניא נמצא יוסף שפירש מאביו עשרים ושתים שנה כשם שפירש יעקב אבינו מאביו דיעקב תלתין ושיתא הויין אלא ארביסר דהוה בבית עבר לא חשיב להו"

1. Yaakov could send messengers to his parents pretty freely.
2. Yaakov was acquired with angels (that he sent to Esau), he could send angels.
3. His father was a millionaire and could afford a better communication with his (only) heir.
4. Yaakov didn't acknowledge his parents of the birth of their grandkids, fulfilling G-d's (and Yitzhok's) plans he was sent to Haran in the first place.

What might be the reasons for Yaakov's lack of honoring for his parents Itzhak and Rivkah?

Comment: Why is 3. a lack of Kibbud Av on Yaakov's part.  What do I care that Yitzchak had everything he needed? Why is 4 different to 1?

Comment: Why would you assume Yaakov didn't send messengers? He could have told them all about his adventures, that still might not be equal to the Kibbud Av Vaem he could have done in person.

Comment: The Gemara you recall is [Megilla 17a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=17&format=pdf).

Comment: @chortkov2 Thanks I rewrote the question.

Comment: Who says he didn’t? None of these questions, as far as I can tell, constitute kibbud av va’em.

Comment: @Loani I tend to think that not serving one's old parents is lack of Kibid. Gemmorah claims that, I'm just trying to specify.