# Reason for Yaakov not rushing to meet back his parents?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Follow-up to "[yaakovs-lack-of-kibud-av-while-in-haran"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96999/sources-for-yaakovs-lack-of-kibud-av-while-in-haran):

Why Yaakov had no plans to see his parents when he returned from Haran, instead he buys a piece of land in Shechem, then moves on and only arrives at his parents' when Yitzhok dies?

Interestingly, Rashi does mention that Yitzhok lived up to selling Yossef to Egypt, however, the last episode in the Torah of him is sending Yaakov to Charan at 120 (of 180).

Comment: I think a better way to phrase your second paragraph, in light of the Rashi you cite in your third, is that Yaakov arrived home 12 years before Yitzchak died.

Comment: @DonielF Please remind me the math. And what happened in those 12 years?

Comment: Yaakov was 130 when he went to Mitzraim, which was 22 years after Yosef was sold, which means Yaakov was 108 when Yosef was sold. But Yitzchak died only once Yaakov was 120. We aren’t told anything about Yitzchak after Yaakov reunites - which, if you do the math counting forward from when he left home (Rashi doesn’t for this one), Yaakov was 99 at that point - and we aren’t told anything about Yaakov from Yosef’s sale until his discovery 22 years later, so we don’t really know anything about those 12 years except that Yaakov spent them in mourning.